# Load response data to FooTable in Nifty

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

can some of you help me with this:
I cannot load the response which I receive from Ajax call. All data-field are equal with the response properties from my model.

Here some code:

```
        url: '/Controller/Action/', 
        type: 'post',  
        data: data,
        success: function (response) { 

            debugger;

            $('.table-recentDecisions').bootstrapTable('load', response.Result.MostRecentDecisions);
            $('.table-recentDecisions').bootstrapTable();

            generateCharts(response)
        }
    });
```

I know that the bootstrapTable must be replaced with something else, but still cannot find the way.

Thanks!